# How to prevent gpg from creating .gnupg directory in user's home directory

Tags: gpg

I'm trying to run use the `gpg` tool to encrypt and decrypt files and I would like to know if it's possible to run this tool without it changing a user's global state. Specifically, running `gpg` for the first time as a given user will cause it to create a `.gnupg` directory and other artifact's in a user's home directory.

I've had some success in isolating the operation of this command from a user's public and secret key ring (see my Ruby gem at https://github.com/rcook/rgpg for how I do this) and  this is the last remaining behaviour of `gpg` I'd like to prevent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass it the `--homedir` argument or use the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable to have it use another directory instead of `.gnupg`.  If you're scripting this, you could create a temporary directory:

```
GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d $HOME/.gnupgXXXXXX)
export GNUPGHOME
```

And then clean up when you're done:

```
gpg ...
rm -rfi $GNUPGHOME
```

Answer (score 5):

*"How to prevent gpg from creating .gnupg directory"*

I had the same issue as described in the question title while checking some key fingerprints on a read-only mounted disk.

The solution I used was adding the `--no-options` flag to the `gpg` command:

```
gpg --no-options  \
    --with-fingerprint /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

As per [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg):

> `--no-options`
>
> Shortcut for --options /dev/null. This option is detected before an attempt to open an option file. Using this option will also
>   prevent the creation of a ~/.gnupg homedir.

If gpg still prints errors that it cannot read user's public and secret keyrings, the redirection `2>/dev/null` will suppress these. Note, however, that exit code of the command may be non-zero in this case, even though the key information is printed.

Comment: I don't believe that this works. It prevents gpg from trying to read the options file from the home directory but doesn't prevent it from trying to write to it. It still errors if gpg doesn't have permission to write to HOME. `gpg: keyblock resource `/home/u/.gnupg/pubring.gpg': file open error
gpg: can't create `/home/u/.gnupg/random_seed': No such file or directory`

Comment: @voxobscuro: The documentation is correct; the errors can be ignored, the command still works though. I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 2):

--no-options doesn't work. it still creates .gnupg folder. However, you can simply do this trick to make it work - Point GNUPGHOME to "/dev/null"

`export GNUPGHOME="/dev/null"`

Then run any gpg command, it won't create .gnupg at all.